# How to setup bitbucket pipelines for AWS Lightsail

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, amazon-lightsail

I have a project with I need to setup bitbucket pipelines for AWS Lightsail.

Is there any documentation regarding on bitbucket pipeline to deploy to AWS lightsail? I've been looking for this on how to configure but haven't found one.

Doc is available for EC2 which is https://medium.com/technext/bitbucket-to-aws-ec2-continuous-deployment-pipeline-using-aws-code-deploy-for-php-application-e39004243cd9

But not for lightsail.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

This process is similar to using GitHub and I've written a detail step by step guide [on my weblog](https://weblog.tiagoperes.eu/automating-apps-deployment-to-amazon-lightsail/). The only difference is when you are in CodePipeline, the source you select isn't gonna be GitHub but Bitbucket (Check available sources [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html)).

Here's the steps you'll need to go through

1. Create a service role.
2. Create an S3 bucket.
3. Create an IAM policy.
4. Create an IAM user.
5. Create a Lightsail instance and install the CodeDeploy agent.
6. Verify the CodeDeploy agent.
7. Setup the application in CodeDeploy.
8. Fork the Bitbucket Repo (this can be optional considering you already have the repo)
9. Setup CodePipeline.
10. Test and Update the Application.

In this particular case the repo I've used already had its [appspec.yml](https://github.com/mikegcoleman/CodeDeployGitHubDemo/blob/master/appspec.yml). You'll need to have one as well but the Medium article you're linking to has that information.